# NTFS Folder Compression Fades

Tags: windows, ntfs, compression, cache

I am on a Windows Server with limited disk capacity. I used windows build in compression of folders to compress a 30 Gbyte file to 22 GByte.

I noticed that while running a programm which frequently accesses little data snippets of that 30 GByte file my used total disk space started to grow. (The size info of said file did not change)

If i stop the programm the disk space stays stable but it is not getting freed up again.

If i reboot the system i am back to the total free disk space i started with after the first compression.

The programm itself does not write any data outside that compressed file. The data is not lost after reboot, so i assume there is a read cache somewhere which i would love to be able to clear without rebooting my machine or disable in the first place to avoid clearing it.

Comment: It appears that writes to compressed files cause some extra clusters to be reserved (observable as an increase in "Total Reserved Clusters" in the output of `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo`). I have so far been unable to clear these extra reservations without a reboot.